# How to Check that a Form Selection is selected to submit the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, select

I have a form with 6 different SELECTION / OPTION HTML drop down lists.  How do I error check to ensure that all 6 SELECTs have been selected before the form is submitted?  If they arent then an ALERT pops up and the form is not submitted.

```
<head>
<script src="http://path/to/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 2;
    $(":input").each(function(){
    if((this).val()==num){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please ensure all fields are selected to submit the form");
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

My form:

```
<form>
Prior History of DVT or PE: 
<select name="prior">
<option value="2">--</option>
<option value="1">yes</option>
<option value="0">no</option>
</select>

...

PE is #1 Diagnosis, or Equally Likely::
<select name="likelydx">
<option value="2">--</option>
<option value=1>yes</option>
<option value=0>no</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: Check each select element's [*selectedIndex*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex) property. If it's -1, then no option is selected. If it's any other value, then one has been selected: `if (this.selectedIndex == -1) {/* no option is selected */}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code. The submit event fires every time an attempt is made to submit the form, and submission can be prevented until the form is validated.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function( event ) {
        if( $('select').filter(function() { return this.value == 2; }).length > 0 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert( 'Please ensure all fields are selected to submit the form' );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vMJA/1/

You need to put your checking code inside an event handler. That event handler listens for the click of the Submit button and prevents submission if the check doesn't work out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 2;

    $("#submit").on('click', function (event) {
        $(":selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==num){
                alert("Please ensure all fields are selected to submit the form");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```